# Can we please stop marking SFMC MobilePush SDK questions as off-topic in Salesforce StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, support, salesforce

Example: [Android Studio Warnings with SDK 4.6.1 [on hold]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143975/android-studio-warnings-with-sdk-4-6-1)

This item is relevant and clear.  In fact, I know the answer to the user's question and it required no additional data, but it has been put on hold by people whom do not work on nor have any familiarity with this Salesforce Product.

Example: [Bluetooth Permission removal on JB4A on Android < 5.0 [closed]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84973/bluetooth-permission-removal-on-jb4a-on-android-5-0)

This item was deemed off topic, but it pertains to the Salesforce Marketing Cloud MobilePush Android SDK.  The question has, again, all the information needed to resolve the customer's question.

There are several other examples of this happening over the past few months and it's making it hard for customers to get answers to questions.

Comment: Looking at these questions, it is easy to see why they look like they do not contain enough information to answer. I am happy to vote to reopen these specific questions, and in general reopening questions is not particularly difficult. It's not by any means a permanent thing.

Comment: Yes please.  After they are re-opened we can move the comment to a proper answer.  Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both got reopened by the community by now as far as I can see. I do think both examples do not make it very clear that they are concerning marketing cloud technologies.

Do please keep making these posts if you detect questions are unfairly closed, **update question subjects and tags to better describe the question as in-scope**.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

This happened again with this question:

[Getting this crash on my crash reporting tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145136/getting-this-crash-on-my-crash-reporting-tool)

The original question just provided a crash dump and not much else, but to be fair to OP all they could really do is ask how to fix it, it was pretty clear that the issue was in the SDK and not their code, granted it's an issue for the actual dev team but that doens't mean there aren't people on this site who know of a workaround.

### Request:

I edited the question to add that, an re-opened it. Can we please show a little more diligence when running through the review queue? Instead of just voting to close, consider if an edit makes more sense and will be enough to make the question fit?

Comment: But if an `Apex` question did the same thing (just an exception dump) it would surely be off topic?

Comment: It would, but that's why I edited to make it a question. Also an Apex question code dump is more generally along the lines of "why is my code throwing an exception" (without including the code), but those that resolve a platform issue would be legit as long as they were phrased correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this one to the list:
[React-Native SFMC SDK - TypeScript definition file is incorrect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293556/react-native-sfmc-sdk-typescript-definition-file-is-incorrect)

The support on the SDKs is horrible in my experience.
Why not use the issues section on GitHub like every other company?

Comment: Hi Zyphrax. SFSE is not the right place to report that a Salesforce product is broken. This is not an official support channel and may not be monitored by the relevant Salesforce employees. I noticed that you said SFMC support directed you to report this issue here. Could you share with me where that referral took place? I work in a different division of Salesforce and cannot help with Marketing Cloud but I do want to be aware if people are being directed here for bug reports.

Comment: I am the team lead on the SDK team and an Android Engineer.  If you are having issues with support for the SDK then that is news to me as none of your questions have reached my team.  Also, I did not flag your question as `off topic`.  The support we provide on SO is voluntary.  If you are not getting what you need here then you should be opening a support case -- if support sends you to StackExchange then tell them to at-mention me on your support ticket.

Comment: Thank you, @BillMote!

Comment: @DavidReed I keep hearing that SFMC support / GitHub / Stack Overflow / StackExchange aren't the right support channels. What is the correct support channel? Where do you want me to post a TypeScript issue like this or that the latest React-Native SDK doesn't compile?

Comment: Bill is the team lead and stated that a support case is the correct route. To be clear, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange have no official relationship with Salesforce. I and other Salesforce employees participate here as community members, but this is _not_ the right venue for reporting possible bugs in Salesforce products _to_ Salesforce. Use official channels for that.